# NoSuchMethodError org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme

Tags: java, websphere, classloader

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V

I'm getting this error running WAS 8.5.  My web app depends on http client 4.1.1 but it seems i'm getting a different class loaded on WAS.  How can I exclude the http client library from my apps class path on was 8.5?

Comment: Are you using IBM RSA for your IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "parent last" classloading so that you use your own classes instead of the ones from WAS.

Change it for the [application](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Fae%2Ftrun_app_classload.html&resultof%3D%2522%2550%2541%2552%2545%254e%2554%255f%254c%2541%2553%2554%2522%2520)
and depending on your configuration for the application on the [webmodule](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Fae%2Fuweb_rwar.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks,  that would have worked. I don't think it's an ideal solution though.  After doing some reading I found that Apache Http Client was mistaken placed on WAS 8.5 class path.  I got around it using an isolated shared library.  Here is the PMR http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM74259

Comment: I was curious, with the Isolated Shared Library, did you add it at the Ear level, or War level?  Also, was it required to set PARENT_LAST in any place?