# Websphere httpclient NoSuchMethodError org.apache.http.conn.Scheme

Tags: java, websphere, classloader, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm seeing the same issue as posted in this thread [NoSuchMethodError org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303522/nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-http-conn-scheme-scheme)

I would like to use httpclient-4.2.5 and tried using an isolated shared library as suggested in the previous post.  (shared library was associated to the app, 2 jars (httpclient-4.2.5.jar and httpcore-4.2.4.jar) were added to the shared lib)

However, it seems to still be loading some classes from com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar

Is there a step I'm missing in setting up the shared lib?

Comment: Did you change the classloader to PARENT_LAST for your application?

Comment: Thanks @Gas, it does work when I changed it to PARENT_LAST.  I was wondering, is setting to PARENT_LAST is a requirment whenever using shared libs, or are there any options that would allow for PARENT_FIRST to work also?

Comment: No, there is no other option, if you want to override classes provided by the server. Parent first will always first look and load classes from the parent (means classes provided by server). You can use parent first, if your shared lib contains non conflicting classes that you want to share across different apps instead of including them in each app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both settings - isolated shared library and PARENT_LAST classloader setting to use your own httpclient libraries.

PARENT_LAST is required to override classes provided by the server.

Comment: Can you share on how you configured the isolated shared library.

Comment: @SuryaChinta just using web admin console, create shared library in the Environment > Shared libraries. Make sure you checked the Isolated library checkbox, while creating library.