# httpcomponents giving error in WAS: NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I am using springrest template to post my xml request and get the response I checked that thing tomcat it is running perfectly but after deploy that thing WAS it is showing following exception.

```
   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory (initialization failure)
```

I searched that it is jar incompatibility. but there are no same jar with different version I checked my code it is giving me error  here

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder=HttpClientBuilder.create();
         HttpClient httpClient=clientBuilder.setProxy(myProxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).disableCookieManagement().build();
         HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentFactory=new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
```

I am using httpcomponent version 4.4. please help me out in this

Comment: You are probably bundling httpclient libs which conflict with WebSphere one. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/28010436/3701228

Comment: I tried that it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I didn't proper get solution.previously we used httpComponents version 4.4. It was creating issue mentioned in question.after we used httpComponents version 3.1.but it is incompatible with resttemplate. so we remove that also. finaly we wrote our code with httpClient version 3.1 like this

```
                            AuthScope  auth=new AuthScope(testAuthData.getHost(),Integer.parseInt(testAuthData.getPort()));



                            ReportData report=new ReportData();

                            report.setEndPoint(input.getEndPoint());
                            report.setRequest(xml);

                                                             Credentials defaultProxyCreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                                                            testAuthData.getUsername(), testAuthData.getPassword());

                            HttpClient httpClient =  new HttpClient();

                            httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(testAuthData.getHost(),Integer.parseInt(testAuthData.getPort()));
                            httpClient.getState().setProxyCredentials(auth,
                                                            defaultProxyCreds);








                            PostMethod post = new PostMethod(input.getEndPoint());

                                               post.addRequestHeader("header1", "header1Value");
                                                                                      post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(xml, "application/xml", null));
                            int responseCode = httpClient.executeMethod(post);
                            //httpClient.ex
            byte[] resp=post.getResponseBody();

            String s = new String(resp);
            System.out.println("response:"+s);
            report.setResponse(s);
   System.out.println("responseCode:"+responseCode);
 Header header=  post.getResponseHeader("header1");
```